# Exception in file choosing

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filepicker

I wrote a macro. But now i want to run in on all files in folder which i choose, **with exception of  files named "Exception1.xlsx" and   "Exception2.xlsx"**. I tried to do it but i am not sure how i can add exception to do while loop(if its right place). Do you have any suggestions?

```
Sub macro()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFil As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog



Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    myFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
  End With



strFolder = myFolder
strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xls*")
Do While strFil <> vbNullString
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFil)

For Each ws In Worksheets

``my working code is here

Next ws

Wb.Save
Wb.Close False
    strFil = Dir
Loop


End Sub
```

Thanks for all responses

Comment: Add a simple `If` before you open the workbook, eg : `If not strFile like "Exception*.xlsx" Then`. Be aware, btw, that you added a backslash to `strFolder`, so you shouldn't add it a second time.

Comment: Okay, what if i cant use "Exception*.xlsx" and 
`If Not strFil Like "Exception1.xlsx" Or "Exception2.xlsx" Then`
doesn't work? What if there are also Exception3.xlsx but i want to run it on Exception3.xlsx file.

Comment: `If strFile <> "Exception1.xlsx" and strFile <> "Exception2.xlsx" Then`

Comment: `If Not strFil Like "Exception1.xlsx" Or "Exception2.xlsx" Then` is not the right syntax. Should be somthing like `If strFil <> "Exception1.xlsx" And strFil <> "Exception2.xlsx" Then`